# Php/sql form population values not submitted

Tags: php, html, sql

Hi have a quick question. Currently I am filling a form with data from a sql query. So for instance they select item number two and the form is filled with the data for item 2 from the data base. I then wish to be able be able to press my update button and have the data that is in the form submitted so that if it is changed in the form it changes  in the data base.
for example:

- item 1 is selected from the drop down list
- enter is pressed
- the page is refreshed and the form is populated with the data from the sql statement in the first submit
- ^^^ this works

I know have the info in the form and want to be able to hit the ubdate button so the old data is passed or type in in values and sub it. The problem is the variables and data that are stored in the form are not passed

Here is the page source

```
enter code here


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Inventory</title>

</head>
<body>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/headercss.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Inventory</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="">Total Inventory</a>
               <ul>
                <li><a href="TotalInventory.php">Total Inventory</a></li>
                <li><a href="NewItem.php">Add new Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="SpecificItem.php">View Specific Item</a></li>

                <li><a href="UpdateItem.php">Update Item</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href="">House Inventory</a>
               <ul>
                <li><a href="#">House Inventory</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Add new Item</a></li>

            </ul>
            </li>


        </ul>
    </div>

</body> <br />
    <form id="addItem" action="/workspace/iventory2/UpdateItem.php" method="post" >

        <select name="items" id="items">

        <option value"sdgssr5y">sdgssr5y</option><option value"a">a</option><option value"sf">sf</option><option value"gsh">gsh</option><option value"cat">cat</option><option value""></option><option value"afdsf">afdsf</option><option value"15">15</option><option value"zzz">zzz</option><option value"nnn">nnn</option><option value"dsdsgfsg">dsdsgfsg</option>     </select>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Enter" name="submit"/>

        <input class="update" type="submit" value="update" name="update"/>      
    </form>
    <form method="post">
        <br />


    <form id="addItem" action="/workspace/iventory2/UpdateItem.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" >

        <label>Item Name: <input name="ItemName" id="ItemName" value="15"/></label><label>CostPrice: <input name="CostPrice"id="CostPrice"value="10"/></label><label>CurrentLevel:<input name="CurrentLevel"id="CurrentLevel"value="10"/></label>   


        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Enter" name="submit"/>   
    </form>

    <form method="post">

</body>
```

Comment: It's not clear what doesn't work, but your HTML is incorrect. You need some space between attributes : <input name="CostPrice" id="CostPrice" value="..."/>.

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the generated HTML code of the form.

Comment: You mean the code for the IDE or from the local host source code?

Comment: The code you get when you right-click in your browser and select "View HTML source". This is the code that the PHP script generates.

Answer (score 0):

Misread the post, sorry. Re-evaluating...

2 Suggestions to try, one is for coding practice, if possible dont use text as the WHERE, assign an ID and pass that instead. You have to take into account case, etc if you use text.

In your HTML, add spaces. name="CurrentLevel"id="CurrentLevel"value=""

Comment: To catch Html errors its always a good idea to run your output against an Html validator like http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Last I checked there was no requirement to have spaces between attributes if they're quoted properly. The only *required* space is after the tag name.

Comment: Other than it being horrible coding practice would that couse the value to not be passed when the update button is passed? For instane
the value I am looking to pass is the row['ItemName'], but it is not being set as the value? When it gets the check to see if it is set, it fails.

Comment: Next problem, your form ids are all the same... Anyhow at the top of your file after the open php tag of course, put print_r($_POST); and look at what is being processed when you click the button. It will help you debug the problem. Unless i have the file/all code involved, i cant really test your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the $_SESSION['item'] variable is set/populated in your code, but I would store that value in a HIDDEN INPUT in your form.

Form code:

```
<form action="" method="post"><!-- Form action="" forces form to submit to itself -->
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="true" /><!-- Tell our script to process -->
<?php
$work = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM Inventory WHERE `ItemName` LIKE '{$_SESSION['item']}' LIMIT 1
");

if ( $work && ( mysql_num_rows($work) > 0 ) ) {

$row = @mysql_fetch_assoc( $work );

echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_to_update" value="' .
$row['ItemName'] . '" />' .
'<label>Item Name: <input name="ItemName" id="ItemName" value="' .
htmlentities($row['ItemName']) .
'"/></label>' .
'<label>CostPrice: <input name="CostPrice"id="CostPrice"value="' .
htmlentities($row['CostPrice']) .
'"/></label>' .
'<label>CurrentLevel:<input name="CurrentLevel"id="CurrentLevel"value="' .
htmlentities($row['CurrentLevel']) .
'"/></label>';
}
```

And the processing code:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['update'] ) ) {

$ItemName = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['ItemName'] );
$CostPrice = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['CostPrice'] );
$CurrentLevel = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['CurrentLevel'] );
$ItemToUpdate = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['item_to_update'] );

mysql_query("
UPDATE Inventory 
SET ItemName='$ItemName',CostPrice='$CostPrice',CurrentLevel='$CurrentLevel'
WHERE  ItemName='$ItemToUpdate'
LIMIT 1
");

$_SESSION['item'] = $ItemName;
}
```